# Using constructors taking objects of non-primitive type from dapper

Tags: c#, .net, constructor, dapper

I am using dapper to read objects that look like this:

```
class MonthlyData {
    public ValueOverride One {get;}
    public ValueOverride Two {get;}
    ...
    public ValueOverride Ten {get;}
    public MonthlyData(
        ValueOverride a
    ,   ValueOverride b
    ,   ...
    ,   ValueOverride j
    ) {
        One = a;
        Two = b;
        ...
        Ten = j;
    }
}
```

The constructor of the target class takes multiple parameters of non-primitive type `ValueOverride`, which is defined as follows:

```
class ValueOverride {
    public decimal Val {get;}
    public bool IsOverride {get;}
    public ValueOverride(decimal v, bool flag) {
        Val = v;
        IsOverride = flag;
    }
}
```

I am reading the data as follows:

```
var res = conn.Query<dynamic>(
    @"SELECT
          COALESCE(o.A, d.A) AS a
      ,   CAST( CASE WHEN o.A IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS bit) AS aFlag
      ,   ...
      FROM MonthlyData d
      LEFT OUTER JOIN MonthlyOverride o
                   ON d.Month = o.Month"
).Select(r =>
    new MonthlyData(
        new ValueOverride(r.a, r.aFlag)
    ,   new ValueOverride(r.b, r.bFlag)
    ,   ...
    ,   new ValueOverride(r.j, r.jFlag)
    )
);
```

This code requires a lot of repetition, so I am wondering if there is a less repetitive approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main problem is that you have a lot of columns which you want to handle the same way.

I would recommend, if possible, to do the following:

1. Unpivot the data database side. You will get a list of column (day?), value and flag, not a row with a lot of values. (this might already be the case in your real data model)
2. Convert every value and flag column using a `Select`.
3. Pivot (`GroupBy`) that data together to return to the original format and the required format of your class.